# Do you have to use mongoose to store an image in MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am struggling to find any documentation on how to store an Image in `MongoDB` with `Node.js`. The only documentation I am finding is storing it with `mongoose`. I am currently using `monk` and would like to just use that instead of `mongoose`. I know I will need to use `GridFS` and `Mulder` but struggling to understand how. If I am able to store an image into `MongoDB` with `Node.js` and `monk` can you give an example. Because I am also having trouble understanding how to properly store it. Would also be great if you could give an example on how to grab the image to display on the browser with `Jaavscript`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Neither `Mongoose` nor `Monk` provides an API to work with GridFS.

You can use either the official [node-mongodb-navtive](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) or [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream).